# Are there any good open source BDD tools for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, testing, bdd

I love the Ruby RSpec BDD development style.  Are there any good tools for doing this with C/C++?

Comment: Is this question about C or about C++? C/C++ is nothing but pure ambiguity.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no mention of [cucumber-cpp](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp), it's an active framework and uses the Gherkin syntax to write the scenarios. It also has a pretty neat set of options to cover many needs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[cspec](http://github.com/arnaudbrejeon/cspec/wikis/home) is for C.  Presumably it will work with C++.  There is a list of tools for various languages on the [Behavior Driven Development Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior_Driven_Development).

Comment: Why is this chosen over cppspec below?

Comment: Possibly because a sentence is more useful than a single word.

Comment: Because he answered first and with an additional link with lots of information.

Answer (score 4):

The original link ([CppSpec](http://www.laughingpanda.org/projects/cppspec)) is dead, but it is still accessible at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/web/) at [CppSpec](https://web.archive.org/web/20080208105001/http://www.laughingpanda.org/projects/cppspec/).

And as  @VickyChijwani already mentioned, there's a copy of the project at [Github - tpuronen/cppspec](https://github.com/tpuronen/cppspec)

Comment: The link is broken. Is https://github.com/tpuronen/cppspec the same project?

Comment: It seems to be the same. Both, the Github repository and [CppSpec](https://web.archive.org/web/20080208105001/http://www.laughingpanda.org/projects/cppspec/) (Internet archive) are signed by Timo Puronen.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you can test your C code using Ruby and RSpec using swig to generate wrappers! See Ben Mabey's post here:
http://benmabey.com/2007/09/09/bdd-your-c.html

I've tried that example out and it worked for me. I'm not sure if anyone has taken it any further.

Answer (score 3):

[Igloo](http://igloo-testing.org/) is one I'm looking forward to try some time

Comment: it doesn't seem to have any of the characteristics of Cucumber nor Fitnesse, the test is still in the code and it is not readable/editable from tester or business analyst.

Comment: I don't think igloo-testing.org is a valid website (at least not any longer).

Comment: @MrMas is correct. URL appears to go to parked domain / redirect to sketchy places. GitHub repo still exists (June 2019) though: https://github.com/joakimkarlsson/igloo

Answer (score 2):

Try [CBehave](https://github.com/bigwhite/cbehave)! It is an RSpec-like BDD framework that uses given/when/then macros. Example:

```
FEATURE(1, "strstr")
    SCENARIO("The strstr finds the first occurrence of the substring in the source string")

       GIVEN("A source string: [Lionel Messi is a great football player]")
           char *str = "Lionel Messi is a great football player";
       GIVEN_END

       WHEN("we use strstr to find the first occurrence of [football]")
           char *p = strstr(str, "football");
       WHEN_END

       THEN("We should get the string: [football player]")
           SHOULD_STR_EQUAL(p, "football player");
       THEN_END
   SCENARIO_END
FEATURE_END
```

Answer (score 2):

Since an RSpec like framework was requested, I'd like to add the recent [igloo](http://igloo-testing.org/). 
Though originally aiming at Context/Spec syntax, it also supports Describe/It syntax. There isn't much noise in setting the test runner and test fixtures up like in those C-based frameworks. It even feels better to look at than CppSpec. They achieve this through use of decent templating mechanics.

Comment: I don't think igloo-testing.org is a valid website (at least not any longer).